# Jython/Python not recognizing for loop

Tags: python, jython, maximo

I found that my for loop is not being ran for some reason.

```
System.out.println("Wann in createLabtransWithDistribution()")

twplset = wombo.getMboSet("EXT_TASKWPLABORVIEW")
twplcount = twplset.count()
totalhrs = 0.0
System.out.printf("Wann in createLabTranswithDist() right before loop. twplcount is %d", twplcount)

for i in range(twplcount) :
    System.out.println("Wann in right after the for loop")
    twpl = twplset.getMbo(i)
    taskhrs = twpl.getFloat("TASKHRS")
    wohrs = twpl.getFloat("WOHRS")
    percenthrs = round ( ( hours * taskhrs *4 / wohrs ))
    percenthrs = percenthrs / 4
    totalhrs = totalhrs  + percenthrs
    System.out.printf("Wann in createDist(). Percenthrs= %d", percenthrs) 
    if totalhrs > hours :
          percenthrs = percenthrs - ( totalhrs - hours )
```

As you can see i've added some debug stuff. I check and twplcount has data (9 to be exact) but i cannot get inside that loop. It seems to be disregarding the entire loop. Any suggestions would be helpful. I am new to Python/Jython.

Edit: After much debugging I got rid of the range and did just 'for in twplcount' and received an error that the int object is not iterable. I hope this helps anyone whos trying to help.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe you're catching and ignoring exceptions from this code? Does code after this loop run?

Comment: I checked the logs and there were no errors or exceptions thrown. Yes the rest of the code runs. This code is actually just part of a defined function in the script.

Comment: So what's the first line that doesn't run?

Comment: The for loop. The System.out line above it works. I wanted to make sure twplcount was getting set and it is. But the for loop isn't getting touched.

Comment: I updated my post with the debug line right after the for loop starts along with the + sign that should be there. Other than what i added there is nothing different. That System.out right after the for loop never prints. The one before the loop does.

Comment: Maybe you could copy and post the actual output to demonstrate what you're seeing. But I have no idea what's happening. In normal Jython or Python, there's no reason that a `for` loop like that wouldn't run.

Comment: SystemOut     O Wann in main right before process daily
 SystemOut     O Wann in process daily()
 SystemOut     O Wann in processDailyWO
'
 00000062 SystemOut     O Wann in createLabtransWithDistribution()

   O Wann in createLabTranswithDist() right before loop. twplcount is 009

Comment: And those are right after each other in the logs in succession so you will know i didn't just copy/paste the readouts

Comment: What happens if you simply print `range(twplcount)` before the loop? Are you sure that it is **not zero**?

Comment: Yea, I'm sure its not zero. Actually the entire value i just checked "010". I was "009". Could there be an issue with the number being represented this way? I tried printing that but was unable to. It has to go to logs and any Jython print statements don't go to the logs. I'm an new at this so I am not sure how to print to the logs using python. Thats the reason for the java print statements.

Comment: That's really weird. I would think you could only see that if the `printf` had `%03d` instead of `%d`. Are you copy-pasting your code or "summarizing" it here? Also, in your posted code, you don't add any newlines in your calls to `printf`. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Is the value of twplcount zero by any chance?

Comment: No. It has a int in it. During debugging i found it is holding a value.

Comment: It may be something really strange, but the most likely explanation is that it just isn't entering the for loop at all. Maybe just try a quick sanity check?

`print twplcount`
`print range(twplcount)`
`for i in range(twplcount) :`
    `print i`